# If Reverse-Flash lost the speed force, and his speed only comes back sometimes, why is he always faster than Barry?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

So I started watching this show just a few weeks ago and binged watched it all the way to the current episode. It's simply amazing. One thing that has been bother me is this....

Dr. Wells says he loses the speed force when he goes back in time to kill Barry's mother.
Apparently, his wheelchair recharges him somehow and he even has a charger on his suit.

But he also said that his speed only comes back in short bursts and for a limited time.

How then, is he always able to beat Barry? He is ALWAYS faster. How is that possible?

Comment: I have not watched this show, but from my understanding the Flash in the show's universe (aside from dodging lightning, apparently) hasn't gone much faster than the speed of sound. That leaves a lot of room to go faster than him.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield, actually, the fastest he has run is a little over Mach 2.  The time travel was an effect of the SpeedForce, not from running FTL.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield, is this not the case in the comics? Does he actually run faster than light in the comics? I kinda like that they are keeping his speed down, a little more realistic, and leaves room for growth. It makes sense to me that the time travel would be an effect of the speed force.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two things going on here:

1. Wells has *way* more experience than Barry does at using his speed. He tends to beat Barry not just because he's comparatively faster, but because he's just plain better at being a speedster. He knows how to use his speed to his advantage, plus he knows how to anticipate The Flash's moves, having fought him so often. Barry, on the other hand, is still new and learning, and Wells is his only speedster antagonist, so he only rarely has a chance to hone his skills.
2. Barry, at least during most of Season 1, wasn't yet at his fastest. Wells only has access to the Speed Force for short bursts as his suit recharges, but when it's charged, he has *full access* to the speed he used to have. Until Barry "catches up", Wells really is faster. (He also knows exactly how long he can use his speed before he has to escape and recharge.)

---

Note, however, that if you've made it into Season 2, then the speedster enemy in Season 2 is a different story. That character *is* described as being outright faster than Barry.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thanks!